# Keep session with Cookies in Jmeter

Tags: session, testing, cookies, jmeter

I am trying to run a simple test in jmeter but i am stuck. The steps are:

1. Log in
2. Set the Cookie Manager
3. Access the landing page

The first 2 steps are successful, but i get status 403 **"errorId":"AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED"** on the 3rd step. My guess is it is not getting the session from log in, but everything i 've tried hasn't worked. Here is my test plan:

[image: testplan]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you share your response also response header

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) obeys [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide), so if you put it as a child of the `Setting Cookies` request it will be applied to **that request only**, therefore cookies will not be available to the `Landing Page`

Try moving the HTTP Cookie Manager one level higher so your test plan would look like:

[image]

You should be able to see which cookies are being received and sent out using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

Comment: I have tried your suggestion too, but then i get **{"status":403,"description":"CSRF Token mismatch"}** . I am new to handling cookies, so any help is welcome.

Comment: You will need to perform the correlation of the CSRF token, in the very first response there is a dynamic parameter which you need to extract using suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), convert into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and replacing the hard-coded (recorded?) CSRF token with the one, you extracted from the first request. See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) article for more details.